# How to edit a content assist behavior in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, eclipse-plugin

Is there a way to edit the content behavior or is there a plugin that does the following ... ?

I have a JSF project

the content assistant completes phrases only for attributes that has getters/setters methods

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ViewScopedBean {

    String name;
    String age;

    public ViewScopedBean() {

    }
    public String method() {
        return null;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

using ctrl+space in `<h:commandButton value="action listener" actionListener="#{myBean.<ctrl+space>}" />` shows only methods and name attribute, is there away to make it also show the age attribute ?

Comment: Do you have getter and setter for age in myBean?

Comment: Why do you want the intellisense to show an inaccessible property which would only cause an exception during runtime?

Comment: @BalusC, I know it doesn't make sense for real but, I DO want to do this, i.e. the auto complete shows all the attributes and methods in the class, I don't know if there is a plugin that can do this or is there something that I can write ?